# Onclick event on holder view in a list view to enable checkbox

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml for generating a listview with a checkbox as below:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/book_check" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="false" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/book_check"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/finger" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Description"
                android:id="@+id/book_descri"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF2500"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my custom class I have the following code to help me manage the data I am getting from my little database

```
private class SbListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SbItem> {
    ArrayList<SbItem> SongBookList;
    public SbListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  
    ArrayList<SbItem> SongBookList) {    
        super(context, textViewResourceId, SongBookList);  
        this.SongBookList = new ArrayList<SbItem>();  
        this.SongBookList.addAll(SongBookList); 
    }
    private class ViewHolder { 
        CheckBox book; 
        TextView title; 
        TextView descri; 
    }
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;  Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        if (convertView == null) {   
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(      
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cc_list_select, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
            holder.descri = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_descri);   
            holder.book = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_check);  
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.book.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {      
                public void onClick(View v) {       
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;     
                    SbItem SbItem = (SbItem) cb.getTag();
                    SbItem.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }   
            });
        } else {     
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
        }
        SbItem SbItem = SongBookList.get(position);    
        holder.title.setText(SbItem.getBook());      
        holder.descri.setText(SbItem.getDescri());  
        holder.book.setChecked(SbItem.isSelected());  
        holder.book.setTag(SbItem);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My desire is that when the text in line one and that in line is clicked that the checkbox is checked or unchecked because currently this only works when only the checkbox is clicked. 
If I try to type cast it just gives an error. For instance this can not work:

```
holder.title.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {      
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;     
        SbItem SbItem = (SbItem) cb.getTag();
        SbItem.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
    }  
});
```

I just needs to work when users click anywhere on that item just like in settings activity.

I have tried to do this:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {      
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;     
        SbItem SbItem = (SbItem) cb.getTag();
        SbItem.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
    }   
});
```

but when debugging the crashes and the error on the console is:

> 08-31 13:25:19.793: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.CheckBox

Comment: You mean you need to checked checkbox when clicked on text ? If yes then simply use `convertView.setOnClickListener()....`

Comment: that generates an error sir

Comment: @Piyush Buddy he want when ever user clicks anywhere on cell the checked will get clicked and viceversa.

Comment: Your code crashes because you try to cast a TextView to Checkbox. when you set a click listener to a view the coresponding method onClick is called with argument View v the view that you originally setted this listener.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

From your activity or wherever you init your listview:

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
//here update the status of your SbItem in the position of your arraylist and then notify the adapter
      sblist.get(position).setSelected(!sblist.get(position).isSelected());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                }
            });
```

Also remove all your click listeners from your adapter.

**UPDATE**

In your SbItem class add setter:

```
public void setSelected(boolean s){
      this.selected=s;
}
```

Also i assume that your getter returns the `selected` property

```
public boolean isSelected(){
          return selected;
    }
```

Comment: I had to reconstruct my listview class yet something is missing from your code. I cant figure out how to update the status of the SbItem. Please finish your code

Answer (score 0):

**Use below event for change CheckBox State**

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: the wrong thing with your code is that its waiting for the checkbox to be clicked which may be had to achieve when user clicks elsewhere in the cell

Answer (score -2):

As your question you need to change your code.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           holder.book.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Now use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for checkbox.

```
 holder.book.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                buttonView.setChecked(true);
                // do your stuff

            } else {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                // do your stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your code, I will try it sir in a few hours time. I wonder why someone would downvote this answer. Instead should have posted his/hers we compare

Comment: your code makes the complier complain: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable holder defined in an enclosing scope looks like if make holder to be final which still generates more errors